# sinのグラフを書こうとしたのですが、エラーになってしまいました何がまずいんでしょうか？

Tags: python

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
X = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(X)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26536\2280643985.py in <module>
      3 y = np.sin(X)
      4 
----> 5 plt.plot(x,y)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: `X`と`x`で大文字と小文字のtypoになっています。

Comment: お恥ずかしい字が誤っていたんですかね

Answer (score 2):

大文字と小文字の違いでエラーになっているように見えます。どちらか一方に統一しましょう。

`X` を大文字で記述している箇所:

```
X = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(X)
```

`x` を小文字で記述している箇所:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました